# Erlang : Mnesia : Is it safe to remove files with prefix _fs?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a couple of files in mnesia directory, like

```
fs_my@node_14585_1263_545605_962084.273
fs_my@node_14702_1263_545842_879762.273 
fs_my@node_14585_1263_545605_962084.290 
...
```

Can I remove them (because it is big files) without risk to lose data?

Why does these files apear? 
What are these files for? 
Is it safe to remove them?

Comment: Move them to another directory and see if it still works... :o)

Comment: they don't look any of the usual mnesia files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file_sorter.html

So without looking into the files, I would say that
1.+4. Yes, you can remove them, but first give it a try, as Zed said.
2.+3. They are temporary files used for sorting and should have been removed. """[...] Temporary files are deleted unless some uncaught EXIT signal occurs."""